# Firefox launched with Selenium differs from System Default Firefox settings

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to gather phonological spellings by requesting `"define"+word` queries from google. As you might know, you will get that dictionary definition for the word after "define" then.

However, when I launch Firefox from Selenium it is launched in a way that makes google be set to German, which is not what I want. When I launch Firefox manually it is set to English, which *is* what I want:

[image]

The problem now is that I will get the wrong results for the same key words:

[image]

The script I use so far looks like this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
capabilities["marionette"] = True
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities)

try:
    browser.get('https://google.com')
    search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
    search.send_keys("define car")
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(5)


except Exception as e:
    print (format(e))
```

How can I make Firefox launched from the script behave as if launched manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force Firefox to accept `en-US` only by setting the `intl.accept_languages` preference, and you can change the country code too:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'en-US, en')
profile.set_preference('browser.search.countryCode', 'US')   

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
capabilities["marionette"] = True

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, capabilities=capabilities)
```

Worked for me. I've also tried to set `intl.accept_languages` to `de-DE, de` and saw the google search page in German.

Alternatively, you can navigate to `http://www.google.com/ncr` ("ncr" stands for "No country redirect") instead of `https://google.com`.

Comment: I have substituted the block of code above the try block with your code, but google is still set to German. My system Language is English too btw. so it comes from the IP.

Comment: @lotolmencre interesting, that works for me for both English and German - I can control the language this way..

Comment: Do you have an IP from an anglophone country though?

Comment: @lotolmencre yup, I've updated the answer and added one more setting you can try to tweak - let me know if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: @lotolmencre another thing to try - what if you navigate to the `http://www.google.com/ncr` instead of `https://www.google.com`?

Comment: Weird, the added settings and the ncr address kind of work, they do the same thing, and show English results, however the result differs from the others still. It is not the German result and not the English one when using .com. For instance the phonological spelling in the box is not IPA as it is when using google.com. I guess I'll better use Wiktionary... But thanks a lot!